# pod not updating package but showing outdated

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to update my pod Intercom to the latest version. pod shows it as needing updating but it refuses to be updated.

```
# pod outdated
Updating spec repo `master`
Analyzing dependencies
The following pod updates are available:
- Intercom 2.3.21 -> 2.3.21 (latest version 3.0.11)
- SevenSwitch 1.4.0 -> 1.4.0 (latest version 2.0.0)
```

But then when I go to update it:

```
# pod outdated
Updating spec repo `master`
Analyzing dependencies
The following pod updates are available:
- Intercom 2.3.21 -> 2.3.21 (latest version 3.0.11)
- SevenSwitch 1.4.0 -> 1.4.0 (latest version 2.0.0)
hopebox:Sonar Mobile michaelleonetti$ pod update Intercom
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using ISO8601 (0.6.0)
Using Intercom (2.3.21)
Using KeenClient (3.5.6)
Using MGSwipeTableCell (1.5.5)
Using SevenSwitch (1.4.0)
Using TPCircularBuffer (1.4)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 6 dependencies from the Podfile and 6 total pods installed.

[!] The `SonarCloud [Debug]` target overrides the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-SonarCloud/Pods-SonarCloud.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

How can I get pod to update to the correct version that is shown in the outdated command?

Comment: did you end up solving it?